# Legend not working for kendo scatter chart date axis and get the series value dynamically using Jquery kendo

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjHs0.png)[scatter chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNtmZ.png)I have a kendo scatter chart date axis and getting the series value dynamically using jquery but I am unable to display the value of legend.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: series: [{
                             name:series[0].name,                            
                            xField: "date",
                            yField: "value"
                        }],

Comment: by adding the      name:series[0].name,      I am getting only 1st value of legend not getting the list of legend value

Comment: My series of code is below                                                                     for (var k = 0 ; k < list.length; k++) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            if ($.trim($(list[k]).text()) == data[i].Key) {                              
                                dataVal.push({ value: data[i].Value, date: new Date(data[i].RecordDate) ,name: data[i].Key });
                            }
                        }
                        series.push({ name: $.trim($(list[k]).text()), data: dataVal });   }

Comment: Can you set up a demo on Plunker?

Comment: Hi I save in plunker

Comment: Can u see the code in plunker

Comment: Can you paste a link?

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/u9bmhodFXlZIVNdqrWoZ/

Comment: My scatter graph doesn't have any issue only legend doesn't working

Comment: I'll explain my request, since I think my intention wasn't clear: The purpose of using Plunker was to recreate your problem there and then I'll we'll have something to look at to both understand the issue better and also see if we can fix it. You just pasted a piece of JS code in the `index.html` file. Can you recreate the problem instead?

Comment: That is the whole code I am using javascript and kendo only.

Comment: Can u plz look into that particular piece of code I am unable to recreate the problem over there (Plunker )

Comment: Data format is like this                                                                                         :
Object
date
:
Tue Oct 04 2016 13:03:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
name
:
"Weight"
value
:
20

Comment: Can you post an image of how the chart looks with the data on it?

Comment: where I should  post the chart?

Comment: How to add the image here plz help me.

Comment: Hi shai plz share your gmail address so that I can share the image of graph

Comment: Edit your question, you'll have an image button in the editing toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

[Scatter chart for Legend not working for kendo scatter chart date axis and get the series value dynamically using Jquery kendo]

Comment: Hi shai I added the image plz check and let me know the solution as soon as possible

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't add an image, you added an answer with a strange content... Look at you question at the top of the page. Right below it, before the comments, there are three "links": share, edit and flag. Click on edit and then in editing mode add an image from the toolbar.

Comment: Please check it now.

Comment: Hi shai, Did you get any solution ?